# Javascript - Agregar punto automático en input para valores de miles

Tags: javascript

Llevo días intentando agregar la función de **colocar el punto automático a un input para valores de miles** (1.xxx / 2.xxx etc), y no lo consigo.

Claro que ayuda mucho que soy novato nivel 0 en JS...

He probado toda clase de inventos, como scripts adicionales para agregar puntos decimales a un input type num **[VER ESTE](https://jsfiddle.net/324hqmd8/)** y **[ESTE OTRO](https://codepen.io/559wade/pen/LRzEjj/)** pero no puedo conseguir que me funcione.

**El siguiente script cumple varias funciones:**

Clona divs, cuenta los clicks dados por el usuario, **suma los valores de los inputs** en los divs clonados y ejecuta un LocalStorage.

El problema que tiene es que **la función que suma los inputs clonados no agrega el punto a los miles**, por cuanto (ejemplo) un valor de 5.400 se queda en 5400 (sin el punto).

Lo dejo tal cual, a ver si álguien me localiza dónde puede ir el puntito de la discordia y me puede ayudar con el código...

Muchas gracias.

**HTML:**

```
<input class="add-prod" value="699"> <!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="899"> <!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="999"> <!--Valores a sumar-->

<div class="cont-num" id="clicks">0</div> <!--Contador de clicks-->
<div class="cont-num" id="clicksdos">0</div> <!--Contador de clicks-->

<!--Aquí se suman los inputs-->

<div id="cont-resultado">
<input name="total" id="total" type="num" readonly="readonly">
</div>

<!--El siguiente div es el botón que realiza las funciones-->

<div class="comp-clone" id="comp-p1" data-clone="cont-p1">Comprar</div>
```

**SCRIPT:**

```
let clicks = 0;
let clicksdos = 0;

const safeInt = (key) => {
  let value = parseInt(getValue(key));
  return (isNaN(value) || value < 0) ? 0 : value;
}

// This loads our clicks from the LocalStorage
const loadClicks = () => {
  clicks = safeInt('clicks');
  clicksdos = safeInt('clicksdos');
}

const loadHTML = () => {
  return getValue('html', '');
}

const loadFromStorage = () => {
  let html = loadHTML();
  if(html !== '') {
    loadClicks();
  }
  displayClicks();
  document.querySelector(".contenido").innerHTML = html;
}

// Display the clicks on the screen
const displayClicks = () => {
    clicks = (clicks === NaN) ? 0 : clicks;
    clicksdos = (clicksdos === NaN) ? 0 : clicksdos;
    document.querySelector('#clicks').innerHTML = clicks;
    document.querySelector('#clicksdos').innerHTML = clicksdos;  
    // Hide / Show Result 
    let display = (clicks > 0) ? 'block' : 'none';
      document.querySelector(".contenido").style.display = "display";
}

const adjustClicks = (value) => {
  clicks +=value;
  clicksdos +=value;
  storeValue('clicks', clicks);
  storeValue('clicksdos', clicksdos);
  displayClicks();
}

const addClick = () => adjustClicks(1);
const removeClick = () => adjustClicks(-1);

// Manage localStorage
const storeValue = (key, value) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.setItem(key, value) : '';
const getValue = (key, defaultValue) => (localStorage) ? localStorage.getItem(key) : defaultValue; 
const storeHTML = () => storeValue("html",document.getElementsByClassName("contenido")[0].innerHTML); 

// Add a node to the Derecha
const addToDerecha = (nodeId) => {
  let node = document.querySelector(`#${nodeId}`);
  document.querySelector('.contenido').appendChild(node.cloneNode(true));
  storeHTML();
  displaySuma();
};

// Monitor ALL click events 
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target;

// Add
  if(target.matches('.comp-clone')) {  
    addClick();
    addToDerecha(event.target.dataset.clone);
  }

  // Remove
  if(target.matches('.bbp')) {
    removeClick();
    getParent('.contenido', target).removeChild(target.parentNode);
    storeHTML();
    displaySuma();
  }
});

// This is just a helper function.
const getParent = (match, node) => (node.matches(match)) ? node : getParent(match, node.parentNode); 

// New Script for sum inputs
const displaySuma = () => document.getElementById("total").value = suma();

const suma = function () {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".contenido div .add-prod"))
              .reduce((a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.value), 0);
}

// Code to run when the document loads.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(localStorage) {
      loadFromStorage();     
  }
  displaySuma();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el objeto [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/NumberFormat), que es un constructor para objetos que permiten un formato numérico sensible al idioma.

Tiene dos formas de uso, por ejemplo: `new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(valor)`, donde `es-ES` sería el formato para España y  `valor` sería el valor numérico. Dado que para España el separador de miles es el punto, te separaría los miles por ese símbolo:

```js
/*
   Referencia a los inputs que tienen la clase add-prod
   para luego sumar cada valor de esos inputs
*/
var toAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.add-prod');
/* Referencia al input del total */
var ibxTotal=document.getElementById('total');
/* Creamos una variable subTotal inicializada a 0 */
var subTotal = 0;
/* 
    Aquí se recorren los inputs con add-prod 
    acumulando sus valores en subTotal
*/
toAdd.forEach(function(item) {
  subTotal += parseInt(item.value);
});
/* 
  Creamos una variable con el valor acumulado en subTotal
  formateado al estilo 'es-ES'
*/
var total = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(subTotal);
console.log(total);
/* Ponemos ese valor en el input del total*/
ibxTotal.value=total;
```

```html
<input class="add-prod" value="699">
<!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="899">
<!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="999">
<!--Valores a sumar-->


<!--Aquí se suman los inputs-->

<div id="cont-resultado">
  <input name="total" id="total" type="num" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Otro uso interesante es si te interesa poner un símbolo monetario. En ese caso le pasarías en el parámetro `options` algo así: `{style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}`. Nótese que aquí le agrega dos posiciones decimales y el símbolo de la moneda indicado.

```js
var toAdd = document.querySelectorAll('.add-prod');
var ibxTotal=document.getElementById('total');
var subTotal = 0;
toAdd.forEach(function(item) {
  subTotal += parseInt(item.value);
});

var total = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES',{style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR'}).format(subTotal);
console.log(total);
ibxTotal.value=total;
```

```html
<input class="add-prod" value="699">
<!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="899">
<!--Valores a sumar-->
<input class="add-prod" value="999">
<!--Valores a sumar-->


<!--Aquí se suman los inputs-->

<div id="cont-resultado">
  <input name="total" id="total" type="num" readonly="readonly">
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias **A Cedano**, me gustan las dos opciones. Muy interesantes y muy útiles. Ahora, para un novato como yo... ¿Dónde agrego para empezar el primer script de tu ejemplo...? ... La verdad es que JS me supera de Galicia a Melilla...

Comment: @Pablo_Web tienes que aplicárselo al valor que quieras, si observas el ejemplo: `var total = new Intl.NumberFormat('es-ES').format(subTotal);` ahí, en `subTotal` tienes la suma de los tres inputs, y lo que haces es crear una variable (`total`) formateada al estilo `es-ES`, luego pones `total` donde tengas que ponerlo, por ejemplo aquí: `ibxTotal.value=total;` esos ya son asuntos del funcionamiento básico de Javascript que debes aprender. Comentaré el código para que entiendas cada paso, pero te toca a ti aplicarlo en el contexto de tu programa. Aquí `subTotal` es la variable que suma tus datos

Comment: Agradezco tu ayuda y apoyo **A. Cedano**, pero la verdad es que no sé implementarlo. No sé dónde vá. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @Pablo_Web en tu código se supone que hay una variable donde recoges la suma de los inputs ¿no? Si a esa variable le aplicas `Intl.NumberFormat` como he hecho en los ejemplos mostrados, y luego usas esa variable para actualizar el valor de tu input `total` ya lo tienes hecho. Es algo básico de Javascript. ¿No tienes identificado eso en tu código? ¿Dónde se acumula el total de inputs? ¿Dónde ese total se usa para actualizar el input que guarda la suma total?

Comment: Vuelvo a darte las gracias, pero empecé con JS hace 10-15 días. Soy tornero CNC, a mi ésto me supera **A Cedano** y a mis 60 y largos ya me cuestan algunas cosas. Gracias, amigo.

Comment: @Pablo_Web pues para tan poco tiempo, veo un código bastante avanzado, con localStorage y todo. He puesto comentarios en el primer ejemplo, para que puedas entender mejor cómo funciona el código. Entendiendo eso sólo es cuestión de llevarlo al contexto de tu programa. Si tienes dificultades en eso, puedes abrir una nueva pregunta con esa nueva duda, que para eso está este sitio. Saludos y ánimo, vas muy avanzado para tan poco tiempo.

Comment: En realidad empecé con ésto por curiosidad, ya sabes, evitar el Alzheimer, y con algo de ayuda edité y mejoré un diseño básico, que era muy malo, la verdad, pero al ver los defectos originales me topé con el dischoso puntito, y me entró la obsesión de arreglarlo, pero no pude. Puedes verlo aquí https://jsfiddle.net/mo0er53p/4/ donde agregué lo tuyo, pero ya sé que ahí no vá...

Answer (score 1):

A la final pude resolverlo con una sóla línea de código.

Lo dejo aquí por si le sirve de ayuda a otros con el mismo problema:

**Original:**

```
const displaySuma=()=>document.getElementById("total").value=suma();
```

**Nuevo:**

```
const displaySuma=()=>document.getElementById("total").value=suma().toLocaleString("es-ES");
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción sencilla es usar algo similar a lo expuesto por A. Cedano en su respuesta, pero sin necesidad de crear un objeto intermedio, usando el método `toLocaleString`:

```js
let numero = 1000000;

console.log('En español', numero.toLocaleString('es'));
console.log('In English', numero.toLocaleString('en'));
```