# Cómo agregar un punto en un valor numérico con JS

Tags: javascript

necesito agregar un punto a los dígitos que tengan un tamaño de 4. Actualmente se muestran los números así **3400** y se debe mostrar algo así **3.400**. Me han dicho con el método subString pero aún no sé cómo funciona bien.

```js
var numero = 4000;

numero.subtring(-1,1);
```

Según el código (no lo he probado aún) me debería retornar 4, y la idea es agregarle el punto. Un detalle es que me parece que el número viene en int, eso habría que convertirlo a String para que funcione el método subtring()

Espero puedan ayudarme gracias!!!

Comment: Buen día, cuantos dígitos puedes ingresar como máximo? o no tiene límites? si es sin límite, tu idea entonces sería hacer separador de miles con `.` o me equivoco?...

Comment: `n=3400; n.toLocaleString('es-AR')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Comment: @Cris223511.dev exacto, separador de miles, pensaba hacerlo de manera manual....

Comment: Puedes mirar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256197/javascript-agregar-punto-autom%c3%a1tico-en-input-para-valores-de-miles?rq=1) o [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/256197/javascript-agregar-punto-autom%c3%a1tico-en-input-para-valores-de-miles?rq=1) para encontrar opciones

Comment: @aloMalbarez en ese caso el formato de AR funciona bien, en mi caso lo puse en CL y funciona correctamente. Gracias por el aporte!!!

Comment: @Emerson si, conviene ser especifico dado que por ejemplo `n=3400; n.toLocaleString('es-US')` usa comas en los miles. de no especificar codigo pais para español por lo general se toma españa. adicionalmente para españa el formato moneda sera € y puede generar algún tema con el signo $ y su ubicación ( dolar en es-US, peso en es-CL )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vendría mejor recorrer el número con ciclo `for` e indicar que si el iterador del `for` sea múltiplo de 3, agregue un `.` después del tercer número que concatenamos, ya que en cada ciclo `for` concateno el número en la cadena.

Podemos hacer esto con esta condicional:

```
if ((str.length - i - 1) % 3 === 0 && i < str.length - 1) {
  resultado += ".";
}
```

En donde verifico que el iterador sea múltiplo de 3 y que también sea menor que el índice del último dígito de la cadena. Esto es para evitar que el `.` se agregue al final de la cadena.

---

Código completo (explicación en comentarios):

```js
function separadorDeMiles(numero) {
  // Convierto el número a string.
  let str = numero.toString();
  // Aquí almacenaremos los resultados.
  let resultado = "";

  // Recorremos el string con for "str.length" veces.
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    // Cada número, lo concatenamos a "resultado".
    resultado += str[i];

    // y luego de concatenar el número, verifico si el iterador es un múltiplo de 3.
    // ponemos "i < str.length - 1" para evitar que el punto se agregue al final del string.
    if ((str.length - i - 1) % 3 === 0 && i < str.length - 1) {
      resultado += ".";
    }
  }

  return resultado;
}

console.log(separadorDeMiles(123));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(1234));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(-1234));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(12345));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(123456));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(1234567));
console.log(separadorDeMiles(-12345678));
```

Comment: Se agradece mucho el tiempo en dar la explicación de aquello, gran respuesta muchas gracias funciona de pana. Y gracias a los demás también por su aporte!!! :)